# json string as json value

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to use a json string as a value of a json? Pass a valid json string as a value of a json element,

I need something like this sample:

```
{
"numberOfBlocks": 2,
"1": ""items": [
    {
        "Id": "111257",
        "Name": "AADbZyXqnVRCHjqWSpqQfgpu",
        "Order": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": "162972",
        "Name": "AADbZyXqnVRCHjqWSpqQfgpu",
        "Order": 1
    }]",
"2":""items": [
    {
        "Id": "111257",
        "Name": "AADbZyXqnVRCHjqWSpqQfgpu",
        "Order": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": "162972",
        "Name": "AADbZyXqnVRCHjqWSpqQfgpu",
        "Order": 1
    }]"
```

}

Comment: Is the value corresponding to `1` a `String` or an `Object`?

Comment: Can be a string or an Object...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, here's a simple example:

```
{
   "a": 3,
   "b": "{ \"c\": \"hello\" } "
}
```

Or something more like what you have

```
{
  "numberOfBlocks": 2,
  "1": "{
    \"items\": [
      {
        \"Id\": \"111257\",
        \"Name\": \"AADbZyXqnVRCHjqWSpqQfgpu\",
        \"Order\": 0
      },
      {\
        \"Id\": \"162972\",
        \"Name\": \"AADbZyXqnVRCHjqWSpqQfgpu\",
        \"Order\": 1
      }]"
}
```

However, not that literal newlines aren't valid in JSON, so you'd need to escape the newlines too. In JS, it would look like the following

```
var a = {
  "numberOfBlocks": 2,
  "1": "{\
    \"items\": [\
      {\
        \"Id\": \"111257\",\
        \"Name\": \"AADbZyXqnVRCHjqWSpqQfgpu\",\
        \"Order\": 0\
      },\
      {\
        \"Id\": \"162972\",\
        \"Name\": \"AADbZyXqnVRCHjqWSpqQfgpu\",\
        \"Order\": 1\
      }]"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes. However, I can see no reason to do that; it would need a lot of escaped quotes. And it makes parsing difficult, apart from that it will confuse everybody who looks at your source.

Comment: Agreed. If you are trying to do this then there is most likely a much nicer way of achieving whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a very large json that takes too long to parse in ie7. I was trying to find a way to process it in smaller pieces. I know that I could have the server to split the data and make several requests to get the data, but it isn't an option right now...

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just need to escape double quotes as `\"` and newlines as `\n`. I don't recommend you do this, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: You need braces and quotes around what comes after `"1"`:, i.e.,  `"1": "{ \"items\" : [...] }"`

Comment: Figured out that strings can't be multiline anyway, so I removed the example.

Comment: escaping all the characters may be too much, but is that or encode/decode with base64...